# Какая характеристика соответствует предложению?

Tags: синтаксис

Астрологи прошлого во многом заблуждались, ими руководила ложная цель, на осуществлении которой и сосредоточивались их усилия.
1) сложноподчиненное 2) сложное бессоюзное 3) сложное с бессоюзной и союзной подчинительной связью между частями предложения 4) сложное со всеми видами связи: бессоюзной, сочинительной и подчинительной.

Answer (score 2):

Это сложное предложение, в нем три части. Первые две связаны бессоюзной связью, третья - союзной подчинительной. Так что ответ №3